# How do I get a list of folder names, which have Chinese names, into an excel sheet?

Tags: excel, unicode, cjk

I know I can list the folders in the command line and copy it into a spreadsheet, but if the folder names are in Chinese, the names do not show up correctly. I guess the command prompt does not support Unicode? I am using an English Windows XP OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about redirecting to a file directly, without going through the console window?

Something like:

```
dir /b path/to/china > folders.txt
```

And then opening the resulting text file in Excel? This *should* get you a text file with the filenames in Windows' filename encoding.